# Asynchronous script loading and excesive load time

Tags: javascript, performance

I know about defer and async, but still I have some doubts about whether async loading is totally async when it comes to UX

All of the JS I have is pipelined into application.js and added to the bottom of the < body > tag.

Now, some of the code there adds other script (for analytics namely) asynchronously like this:

```
script = document.createElement('script')
script.type = 'text/javascript'
script.src = 'http....js'
document.body.appendChild(script)
```

all good... JS doesn't block rendering, gets executed after being loaded etc., but there is one question, though! What happens if the script loaded asynchronously is being loaded for 15 sec like in the case of one tracking tool we just added?
I can notice that the page is not being unresponsive, the DOM ready is fired of course, but what happens with the images that could still be loading or the rest of Javascript that comes in application.js after `.appendChild(script)`?

Answer (score 0):

appendChild only adds a script element to the document body.

The downloading of the script element will only start after its been added to the body.
This will not block the execution of javascript after the appendChild.

Nicholas C. Zakas wrote a good article explaining how it works [article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/23/loading-javascript-without-blocking/)

Comment: hi Marco, the part about affecting the rest of JS is clear now since the JS execution is single threaded and newly loaded script gets executed last, but what about the load of other resources if the 15sec loading is added to the rest of the resources to be loaded? Imagine you have a lot of async fired ajax calls, images being loaded etc. and now you have 15s loading JS added to the equation :) ? Thank

Comment: One comment from http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/23/loading-javascript-without-blocking/ @Madhu – JavaScript is single-threaded... What we’re talking about is not JavaScript executing but rather JavaScript being downloaded. ... When creating a dynamic script tag, the code is handed to the JavaScript engine for execution, but that queuing doesn’t block the page like it would if the script tag were embedded in the page statically.